# windows command line dir command: to display only the file name, in 8.3 format?

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

I know that "dir /w" or "dir /b" shows only the file name.
While "dir /x" or "dir /X" shows the 8.3 format, but together shows all other information like long format file names, dates and size.

is it possible to call `dir`, that only shows the file names (not showing dates or sizes), and showing that in 8.3 format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for /R %A in (*.*) do @echo %~nsA %~nA
```

without subdirectory:

```
for %A in (*.*) do @echo %~nsA %~nA
```

add hidden files:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /B/A:-/S *') do @echo %~nsA %~nA
```

without subdirectory:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /B/A:- *') do @echo %~nsA %~nA
```

Comment: can you include output that proves it does that

Comment: How would I get it to kick the results of that first command into a text file? I get the following error: "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the 8.3 names and nothing else to be displayed, if you use "dir /-n" you will get the 8.3 name at the beginning of each line. Note: it separates the extension from the filename with a space rather than a period.

```
C:\Users\User>dir /-n
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5C60-1B61

 Directory of C:\Users\User

.             <DIR>             01/28/2015  11:26 PM
..            <DIR>             01/28/2015  11:26 PM
Contacts      <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
Desktop       <DIR>             01/25/2015  05:06 PM
DOCUME~1      <DIR>             01/27/2015  10:20 PM
DOWNLO~1      <DIR>             01/27/2015  10:10 PM
FAVORI~1      <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
GOOGLE~1      <DIR>             01/28/2015  02:08 AM
Links         <DIR>             01/25/2015  05:06 PM
Music         <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
Pictures      <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
SAVEDG~1      <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
Searches      <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
TESTIN~1 TXT                  8 01/28/2015  10:32 PM
TESTIN~2 BAT                175 01/28/2015  11:26 PM
TESTIN~1 BAT                164 01/28/2015  11:26 PM
UNIGIN~1      <DIR>             10/28/2014  07:01 PM
Videos        <DIR>             12/27/2014  04:46 PM
               3 File(s)            347 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  3,896,034,717,696 bytes free
```

But you can use the "dir /-n" within a [for loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) in a batch file then [extract a substring](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2009/02/14#var-substr-extraction) of the first 12 characters to get rid of the rest of each line. E.g.:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=7 tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /-n ^| find /v "File(s)" ^| find /v "Dir(s)"') do (
   set x=%%i
   echo !x:~0,12!
)
```

The "skip=7" skips the first 7 lines, which aren't file nor directory names and the output of the "dir /-n" is piped through two find commands to remove the last two lines produced by "dir /-n" (the pipe symbol "|" needs to be "[escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)" by a "^". Since the substring extraction occurs in a for loop in the batch file, "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" is needed and "!" needs to be used with the variable x rather than "%". For the above example, you would then see the following output from executing the batch file:

```
C:\Users\User>testing456
Contacts
Desktop
DOCUME~1
DOWNLO~1
FAVORI~1
GOOGLE~1
Links
Music
Pictures
SAVEDG~1
Searches
TESTIN~1 TXT
TESTIN~2 BAT
TESTIN~1 BAT
UNIGIN~1
Videos
```

Comment: Nitpick: one or more spaces. Try creating a file named `abc.txt` to see this in action. Then, for the fun of it, create a file named `abc.docx`.

Comment: On my Windows there is no separator, so the extension looks like part of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %i in (*) do echo %~nsxi
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=4" %i in ('dir /a-d /x "%cd%" ^| find "/"') do echo %i
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %i in ('dir /a-d /-n "%cd%" ^| find "/"') do echo %i.%j
```

or to include directories/folders:

```
for /f "tokens=4" %i in ('dir /x "%cd%" ^| find "/"') do echo %i
```

Tested in Win 10

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for an hour I came up with the following:

**from dos prompt:**

```
for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /B/A:-/S c:\Windows') do (@echo %~sA>> "%temp%\file_list_8dot3.txt")
```

**from .BAT or .CMD file:**

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /B/A:-/S c:\Windows') do (@echo %%~sA>> "%temp%\file_list_8dot3.txt")
```

***note:*** *this script still has problem with long file names, but it will continue and make a 8dot3 text file that can then be pumped into any other batch file.*

**The following is my whole test .Bat file:**

```
@echo off
cls

set ll=%temp%\file_list_8dot3.txt

if exist "%ll%" del "%ll%"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /B/A:-/S %temp%') do (@echo %%~sA>> "%ll%")

start /wait notepad "%ll%"

if exist "%ll%" del "%ll%"
```

Answer (score 0):

To list files into all sub directories try this one out:

```
for /d /r %i in (*.*) do dir "%i" /B > %i/test.txt
```