# Batch Files: List file names and folder names

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

With cmd or .bat scripts, is there a way to list only file names and folder names? I would like to run a batch file to produce a text file that contains this information.

Suppose I have the following folder:

```
C:\test\test.bat
C:\test\Doc1.exe
C:\test\Doc2.docx
C:\test\subdir1\Doc3.pdf
C:\test\subdir2\Doc4.txt
```

I'd love to have an output like this:

```
Doc1.exe
Doc2.docx
test.bat
subdir1
subdir2
```

So far, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/870934) is the closest I could get. With an output of:

```
Doc1     exe
DOC3~1   DOC
subdir1
subdir2
test     bat
```

I've tried dir:

```
dir /b /a-d >filelist.txt
```

But it didn't get what I wanted. (i.e., it only list file names but not folder names).

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with just `dir /b`?

Comment: You're right, dir /b gets what I wanted. Perhaps I confused it with dir /d. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**
Exclude the `/a-d` from your code and it should be exactly what you want it to do.

Also, to get the exact output format you specify, order the return by whether the item is a folder.

**Explanation**

https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html

`/a` is to specify an attribute
`d` specifies to look for directories, and the `-` is negating the `d`
so `/a:-d` means: where attribute is not directory and that parameter is taking away your directories from the list.

A simple `dir /b` will return all folders and files.

The parameter `/o` lets you organize the return. `/o:g` will list folders first in the list, and `/o:-g` will list them last.

Finally, if you ran `dir /b /o:-g > filelist.txt` your return would be

```
Doc1.exe
Doc2.docx
test.bat
subdir1
subdir2
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I especially appreciate the last part about the g vs -g modifier. I'll be sure to read the info in the link you've provided.